# How to prevent action execution in OnActionExecuting of class that is inhereted from the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to check some conditions from request before action and decide whether to perform the action or not. I need this for all the actions of controller. For this, I make base controller inherited from standart MVC Controller class.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
     {

           //some code
           ...
           if(condition)
           {
             //not executeAction
           }
           base.OnActionExecuting(context);              

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have quickly found the answer. You need set Context.Result property. 
For instance.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
        if(context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("key"))
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;              
            NotExecuteAction = true;
        }



        if (NotExecuteAction)
        {
            context.Result = NoContent();
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);           

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not friendly with JQuery Ajax. You better use:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    if(context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("key"))
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;              
        NotExecuteAction = true;
    }



    if (NotExecuteAction)
    {
        context.Result = Content("");
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(context);           

}
```

This way, an empty result will be thrown.